# What is the difference between 960RGB and 1920RGB?

Tags: display

In MIPI DSI display resolution, what is the difference between "960RGB * 1920" and "1920RGB * 960"?

Comment: is it orientation?

Comment: @jsotola Yes, you are right. Thank you.